# Какие виды защиты нужны для финансового сайта с балансом, помимо защит от xss, csrf и frode атак?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, безопасность

Хочется исключить взломы баланса и покупок. Какие есть еще способы атак на финансовые сайты помимо перечисленных и как от них защититься?

Comment: Ну, например чтобы пользователь не мог отправить -100500 и его баланс вдруг стал больше, а не меньше.

Comment: @lampa тоже об этом думал, есть статьи как проверку такую сделать, не хочу велосипед изобретать, так как на кону доверие к ресурсу и возможные финансовые потери?                        с фрикассой если работать

Comment: интересуюсь спросить, что такое "frode атака" и как от неё защищаются.

Comment: @Ипатьев https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ENPL3QE1J7w&t=611s, хороший ответ вы дали конечно, но меня самого интересует этот вопрос, хотелось подчекрнуть для себя еще виды атак и взломов, если бы я хотел, то уже нанял бы специалиста и не писал тут на форуме, логично?)

Comment: Я вас очень прошу, не надо учить компьютерную безопасность по видео, записанным школьниками на ютубе. Ни к чему хорошему это не приведёт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вид защиты тут может быть только один - найм **грамотного специалиста** по компьютерной безопасности, который будет заниматься организацией.

Я думаю, все мы боимся попасть ко врачу, который перед операцией будет писать на форум "коллеги, тут аппендицит надо удалить, напишите, чо там куда резать?". Врач должен уже знать что делать, перед тем, как его допускают к пациенту. То же самое касается серьезной компьютерной безопасности. Безопасность, построенная по ответам на форуме - это какой-то анекдот.